# How can $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n} \frac{|x_n-z_n|}{1+|x_n-z_n|}$ be symmetric?

Tags: functional-analysis

How can $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n} \frac{|x_n-z_n|}{1+|x_n-z_n|}$ be symmetric?

Problem:

Consider that the sequences are s.t. they obey:

$(x_n)$ follows $f(x)=x^3$

$(z_n)$ follows $f(x)=x^2$

Then [the graph of this is unsymmetric.](https://www.google.fi/search?client=opera&hs=cJ7&ei=0wk5XKfeB-fprgTcyrroBg&q=abs%28x%5E3-x%5E2%29%2F%281%2Babs%28x%5E3-x%5E2%29%29&oq=abs%28x%5E3-x%5E2%29%2F%281%2Babs%28x%5E3-x%5E2%29%29&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39j0i8i30.4322.4322..4530...0.0..0.54.54.1......0....1..gws-wiz.ZA7dE6G6RSQ)

Comment: It is symmetric in the sense that if your interchange the roles of $x_n$ and $y_n$, you get the same value.  Not that $x_n = x_{-n}$.

Comment: @kimchilover Okay see, mixing the meaning of "symmetric".